# Como cargar el DropDown en Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

He tratado de diferentes formas de cargar el `dropdown` desde mi **DB** al `jqgrid` pero la verdad no lo consigo , la idea es mostrar el `dropwdown` y establecer el `selected` que lo traigo desde mi **DB**. Adjunto captura:

[image: captura]
En responsable debería cargar mi `dropdown`, no lo hace sin embargo si trae la data desde mi **DB** para llenar dicho `dropdown`:

[image: result personal]

Para llenar la grilla trae la siguiente `data`:

[image: llenar]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 var combobox_personal = $.ajax({
        url:'/listadoPersonal',
        async:false,
        success:function(data, result){
            if(!result){alert('erro ar cargar');}
        }
    }).responseText;

   var sac_id=1;
   var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    $("#grid_plan_accion").jqGrid({

        url:'/selectPlanAccion',
        postData: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrftoken, 
            id_sac: sac_id,
        },
        datatype: 'json',
        colNames: ['DETALLE<', 'PLAZO', 'RESPONSABLE', '<span class="badge bg-green">ACCIONES</span>'],
        colModel: [
                { label: 'detalle_plan_accion', name: 'detalle_plan_accion', width: 170, sorttype: "string", editable: true, edittype:"text"},
                { label: 'plazo_plan_accion ', name: 'plazo_plan_accion', width: 40, sorttype: "string", editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                {name:'responsable_plan_accion_id',index:'responsable_plan_accion_id', width:100, editable:true, edittype: "select", formatter:'select',editoptions: { value: combobox_personal} }, 
                { name: "Acciones", formatter: buttonEliminarFormatter, width: 90, align:'center', search: false, 
                    sortable: false, hidedlg: true, resizable: false, editable: false, viewable: false
                }
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        width:800,
        height: 200,
        //data:'mydata',
        caption:'PLAN DE ACCION',
        shrinkToFit: true,
        pager: '#pager_plan_accion',
        cellEdit: false,
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
        editurl: "clientArray",
    });
```

No se cual sea el error quiza alguna sugerencia...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basare mi respuesta de cuando ya hace tiempo utilize jqgrid, y para esos tiempo tenian formatos en especifico para la creacion de select option:

Tu variable `combobox_personal` deberia de tener el siguiente formato:

Tipo cadena:

```
combobox_personal = "1:Diego Avila; 2:Julia Pazmino; 3:Vinicio Coello"
```

ó

Tipo json:

```
combobox_personal = { 1:'Diego Avila', 2:'Julia Pazmino', 3:'Vinicio Coello' }
```

> Tambien verifica que cuando hagas `editoptions: { value:
>   combobox_personal }` ya `combobox_personal` esta llena con la
>   informacion.

Cuando hagas el llamado a `'/listadoPersonal'` puede formatiar el valor que trae la consulta o devolverla ya con algunos de esos formatos en la consulta.

Por ejemplo (suponiendo que `combobox_personal` es un json, si no, lo parseas):

```js
var combobox_personal = [{ nombre:'Diego Avila', id:1}, {nombre:'Julia Pazmino', id:2}, {nombre:'Vinicio Coello', id:3 }];

var arr_personal = [];

for(var i in combobox_personal) {
    arr_personal.push(combobox_personal[i].id + ":" + combobox_personal[i].nombre);
}

combobox_personal = arr_personal.join("; ");

console.log(combobox_personal);
```

Answer (score 3):

solo debes cambiar:

```
editoptions: {value: combobox_personal}
editoptions: {value:JSON.parse(combobox_personal)}
```